# Is there a way to redirect stdout to a function while in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to redirect the print output of a function to another function, while in a loop. My code processes stdin line by line, so each time a line is printed to stdout I want to use it as the "stdin" for another function. I've read stuff like contextlib but the examples I've seen are to redirect it to another file. Is there a way to do this?

```
def foo():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        doSomething...
        print(...)

def bar():
    for line in sys.stdin: # stdin is stdout from foo()
        doSomething...
        print(...)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. **Why** do you want to do this? There are much simpler ways to communicate information between functions. You do understand that displaying text with `print` has *nothing to do with* getting information into or out of functions, yes? And that there are built-in ways to do that (passing information in via arguments and parameters, and out via the `return` value)?

Comment: It also isn't clear: are you hoping that the functions will in some way run simultaneously? Such that, for example, `bar` will wait at the end of a loop until another line of output has been produced by `foo`, and then run the loop again with that line?

Comment: "stdin is stdout from foo()" It's hard to make sense of this request, because functions don't have a stdin or stdout - there is *one* of each for *the entire program*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel `return` or using parameters will exit out of the loop, and since I'm reading stdin one line at a time I cannot store the lines (into a list for example) and have to process it in real time. So when a function prints into stdout I want to pass the stdout onto another function without exiting the loop. Is this possible?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes that's what I meant

Comment: That doesn't really help with understanding. Why doesn't it work to store the lines? If the lines were stored, `bar` could just iterate over the lines, which would each be a separate item in a list. What do you mean exactly by "in real time"? "So when a function prints into stdout I want to pass the stdout onto another function without exiting the loop" Why not just write a function that handles *one* line, and *call it from foo*?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The functions are independent of each other and can be called on its own, so I can't force one to accomodate another.

Comment: Why do you have to use `print` to communicate?

Comment: @wwii because that's the main purpose of the function. Communicating to another function is another functionality I want to add without breaking the loop of the existing functions

Comment: Why do you have to read from sys.stdin .

Comment: With an answer in hand, you  persisted in asking for the impossible - perhaps you can provide an example of input that could be provided to the program you're imagining and the output that it would generate as a response to that input - and explain why the setup you're proposing is needed for that, from your perspective.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments, what you're explicitly asking cannot be done, or rather doesn't really make sense.

However, what you want to achieve can be done easily. For example, if `script.py` is:

```
import sys


def foo():
    # this is the only place where you'll be reading from stdin
    for line in sys.stdin:
        # yield one value from the generator, then continue
        yield line.lower()  # each line in lowercase


def bar():
    # here you just start and then exhaust the generator
    for result in foo():
        print(f'"{result}"')  # put quotes around each result and print


bar()
```

If you create a text file `test.txt` with these lines:

```
Mary had a little lamb
Hello world!
SOME MORE...
```

And run the command `type test.txt | python script.py` (on Windows command prompt, similar commands for other platforms), the output will be:

```
"mary had a little lamb"
"hello world!"
"some more..."
```

Someone asked why you also need to print from `foo()` and you replied that this is a required part of the function - there is of course nothing stopping you from both yielding and printing:

```
def foo():
    # this is the only place where you'll be reading from stdin
    for line in sys.stdin:
        print(line := line.lower())  # each line to lowercase
        # yield one value from the generator, then continue
        yield line
```

Comment: In this case, bar() is dependent on foo() and loses its ability to read from stdin by itself. Is there a way for bar() to be able to read from stdin or from another function while having it be interchangeable (foo can take input from stdin, or bar, vice versa)

Comment: People have already told you "no" several times and explained why, but you seem to be unwilling to accept that your script/program will only ever have one standard input, and you cannot have two functions somehow running concurrently and both reading from it. If you really need that (and that's extremely doubtful given the fact you're asking these questions) you should write both scripts as functions and tee up the input to both of them running separately. If you need them to communicate with each other within a single program, standard in and standard out are simply the wrong place to look.

Comment: To put it another way: assume a line arrives on standard in - which function do you expect to read it? `foo()` or `bar()`? And if the answer is both, what do you expect to happen when they write to standard out - how are they supposed to know what is written by the other? How would you avoid infinite recursion? And if you have an answer to that - why doesn't that solution work with generators or message passing instead of using a tool that's entirely unsuited for the job? It would be a lot easier if you provided an example of a task that you think requires this.